# NSwag - Separate file generation

Tags: angular, nswag

I'm using NSwag to generate my TypeScript client (Angular format), but I'm having problems with implementing Bearer token authentication because of circular dependencies.

My user service needs to import the TS client to use the token DTOs and my TS client needs to import the user service to inject the token.

As such, I was wondering if it was possible to split the generated file into two (or more) client and model files.

Another option is to implement an interceptor on the HTTP requests, but I find that abhorrent since it could cause problems if I use another API.

Comment: Not implemented yet, see https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/issues/1398

Answer (score 2):

We've run into this problem but we're planning on doing this the other way around.

1. curl the swagger document
2. rummage through it and split it based on tags
3. create local swagger documents for each tag
4. run nswag cli against each newly created swagger document

That way we don't have to alter the server just because the client needs something else.

I've successfully broken down the schema to multiple schemas, one per controller, and generated new files through nswag. Not the prettiest code but it works.. Could publish it on github if any one is interested

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate NSwag configurations and run each one. This is the only way to achieve what you are looking for as of right now.

This will not work during build using the normal convention and will need to be modified in the proj file as maybe a powershell script to run Pre or Post process.

Answer (score 0):

I found you can do this using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger instead of NSwag.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger?